# Python function to extract one word from a sentence

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I have been running Mac Terminal Commands in Python. Below is one such command, *sudo fdesetup status*, which checks whether Filevault on my Mac is turned on:

```
p = subprocess.run("sudo fdesetup status", shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
print(p.stdout, p.stderr)
```

The sample output of the command is as below, either on or off:

```
Filevault is turned off
```

But i only want the line after "is", so i only want to see either **"turned on"** or **"turned off"**. I have been trying the below "grep" commands which i have found online:

```
grep -E -v 'Filevault is'

egrep -v 'Filevault is'

grep -E -o 'Filevault is'

egrep -o 'Filevault is'
```

However all i receive is CalledProcessErrors so far. Is there a solution to my predicament?

Comment: no mac here - but something along the lines of `f = re.findall(r"Filevault is (.*)",p.stdout)` should work (you need to `import re`) first. (returns a list of matches, check if any, use first or all etc...)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Does the sample output always consist of either "turned off" or "turned on"?